# Expressing a open-high-low-close price series on standard basis

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Say I have some stock-price time series expressed as follows:

```
open = [o(1), o(2), ... o(n)]
high = [h(1), h(2), ... h(n)]
low = [l(1), l(2), ... l(n)]
close = [c(1), c(2), ... c(n)]
```

I would like to express them on a 100-basis so that I can compare their patterns not depending on the unit measure. What I did so far for every series is:

Starting the open from 100 and computing the following values by using the daily change:

```
o(1) = 100
o(2) = o(1)*change(2)
...
o(n) = o(n-1)*change(n)
```

where

```
change(k) = [o(k)-o(k-1)]/o(k-1)
```

So far the pattern of the 100-based time series is the same of the originary one:

[image: Open Standardization]

After this, I have computed the remaining three series (high, low, close) expressing them as the increase/decrease of the open price series. For example, in the originary series the high can be expressed as:

```
h(k) = o(k) + [(h(k)-o(k))/o(k)]*o(k)
```

that means

```
h(k) = o(k)*[1+[(h(k)-o(k))/o(k)]]
```

So, naming

```
ch(k) = 1+[(h(k)-o(k))/o(k)]
```

I have created one vector called 'ch'

```
ch = [ch(1), ch(2), ... ch(n)]
```

and so created a "standard-high" vector such as

```
high = [o(1)*ch(1), o(2)*ch(2), ... o(n)*ch(n)]
```

The result is the following:

[image: High standard]

I am clearly being conceptually wrong somewhere, but I can't figure out where. Can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: You're going to use some strange (to my mind) "normalization" scheme. Are you interested in description of a more standard way to normalize data?

Comment: @werediver why not? The reason why I was doing this is (to my mind) that for keeping the range width of the prices I should have expressed the others as percentage of one series (that would have been the normalized one, and looking at the chart it seems to be actually normalized). But if you have a more standard way to normalize these data I'm glad to know it!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to normalize your data:

1. Fit to $[-1, +1]$;
2. Discard the mean and normalize standard deviation.

See the image attached for illustration.

Both ways are pretty standard. Note that the latter method is less prone to random spikes in the data.

Here is [Scilab](http://scilab.org) code for both methods.

```
// 1. [-1, +1] range

Max = max(H)
Min = min(L)
Range = (Max - Min) / 2

O1 = (O - Min) / Range - 1
H1 = (H - Min) / Range - 1
L1 = (L - Min) / Range - 1
C1 = (C - Min) / Range - 1

// 2. Zero mean, unit standard deviation

Mean = mean(C)
Sig = stdev(C)
C2 = (C - Mean) / Sig
```

Also I want to note the following:

- Open price is usualy close to the previous close price;
- High and low prices can be roughly estimated by [Bollinger bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollinger_Bands).

Therefore you may want to drop open, high and low prices and take only close prices. This allows you to apply more methods from statistics and digital signal processing to your stock data.

[image: enter Normalization]